# How to fix Bootstrap 3 responsive issue with hidden/visible on scaled screen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive, scaling

I am running an app with bootstrap 3.3.7 and have an issue with resizing on a scaled screen.

When setting a width of `$container-width - 1px`, all `visible-*` and `hidden-*` get ignored. It works on 100% scaling but with 125% and upwards it fails.

I have the following demo code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrapd/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div>SM=768,MD=992,LG=1200</div>
  <span class="visible-xs">XS</span>
  <span class="visible-sm">SM</span>
  <span class="visible-md">MD</span>
  <span class="visible-lg">LG</span>
  <hr>
  <span class="hidden-xs">XS</span>
  <span class="hidden-sm">SM</span>
  <span class="hidden-md">MD</span>
  <span class="hidden-lg">LG</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Way to reproduce:

- Set the scale to 125%.
- Set the window width to 766px (e.g. with key F12) => OK (XS).
- Set the width to 767px => bug appears (no display).
- Set the width to 768px => OK (SM).

Another way on FHD-Screen:

- Set the scale to 125%.
- Pin the browser window to a side (half screen)

Environment: Win10, Chrome latest version (bug also appears on Firefox)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution! Since I'm working with SASS, I added the following to my `_variables.scss`:

```
$screen-xs-max: $screen-sm-min - 0.1;
$screen-sm-max: $screen-md-min - 0.1;
$screen-md-max: $screen-lg-min - 0.1;
```